# WooCommerce Checkout - Validate User Role

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm facing a challenge with WooCommerce's checkout process. I use the "B2B for WooCommerce" plugin to differentiate between regular and B2B clients.

I have two product categories "regular" and "B2B". The regular products are available to all visitors by default. Here's what happens:

1 - A visitor adds products from the "Regular" category (intended for regular clients) to their cart.
2 - On the checkout page, the visitor decides to register as a B2B client.
3 - The registration and checkout processes occur simultaneously on this single page.

I want to prevent the order from being placed if a user is registering as a B2B client and has "Regular" products in their cart. Since both actions (registration and checkout) happen at once, typical WooCommerce hooks aren't working as expected.